# C++: Immutable method versions

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11, what is the best way to provide two versions of a method, one to modify the object itself and one to return a modified copy?

For example, consider a string class which has the "append(string)" method. Sometimes you might want to use append to modify your existing string object, sometimes you might want to keep your string object the same and create a copy.

Of course, I could just implement the first version and manually create a new object everytime I need one but that adds multiple temporary variables and lines of code to my project.

If it is still not clear what I am trying to do:

```
String s1("xy");
String s2 = s1.appendCopy("z");
s1.appendThis("w");
// s1 == "xyw"
// s2 == "xyz"
```

In Ruby there is a concept (or rather, a naming convention) which says for such methods, there are two variants: append (creates a new String) and append! (modifies this object)

C++ does not have something like this, so I would be stuck with ugly method names like "appendCopy".

Is there a good way to implement what I am trying to do?

So far, the best idea I had would be to make the modifying versions class members and the copying/immutable versions static methods which take the object to work on as a const argument.

Comment: I think the usual convention is to choose one or the other and stick with it, not try to implement both in the same class.

Comment: You could use a free function to modify neither, expressing the symmetry of the operation. Something like `join(s1, "z")`.

Comment: `append` is not exactly a good example since `s1 + "z"` appends without modifying `s1` ;)

Comment: You don't need to declare temporary variables to use temporaries: `String(s1).append("z")`

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oh, and since Yakk invented named operators, we can also use `s1 <join> "z"` for arbitrary operations (or `s1 *join* "z"`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is actually a guideline, expressed by Herb Sutter in [GotW #84](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm):

> Prefer non-member non-friend functions.

In your specific case, `append` (in-place) requires modifying the existing `string` so is well-suited to be a class-method, while `append` (copying) does not, so (following the guideline) should not be a class-method.

Thus:

```
void std::string::append(std::string const&);

inline std::string append(std::string left, std::string const& right) {
    left.append(right);
    return left;
}
```

---

After popular request, here are two overloads that can be used to optimize performance. First the member-version that may reuse its argument's buffer:

```
void std::string::append(std::string&& other) {
    size_t const result_size = this->size() + other.size();

    if (this->capacity() < result_size) {
        if (other.capacity() >= result_size) {
            swap(*this, other);
            this->prepend(other);
            return;
        }
        // grow buffer
    }

    // append
}
```

And second the free-function that may reuse its right-hand buffer:

```
inline std::string append(std::string const& left, std::string&& right) {
    right.prepend(left);
    return right;
}
```

*Note: I am not exactly sure there are not ambiguous overloads manifesting. I believe there should not be...*

Comment: You can optimize the free function by recycling either argument if it's an rvalue. But I'm not quite sure how to do that elegantly.

Comment: @dyp, it looks like that's what the example code is doing.  (At least, it's recycling the left argument; recycling the right argument is often problematic for exponential-growth-buffer-type objects and `append`.)

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson It's only half the optimization, and the other half is what could be applied in the OP's example.

Comment: @dyp, I think I'm dumb this morning.  Can you clarify what the other half of the optimization is?  It looks to me like based on this answer, the OP's code would be written as: `String s1{"xy"}; String s2 = append( s1, "z" ); s1.append("w");`, and I'm not sure what else to optimize here.  Unless you're talking about recycling the right hand temporary, but I don't know how to implement that efficiently with typical string-type implementations.

Comment: @dyp But what would you want to "recycle" from `right`?

Comment: @Solkar Recycling always recycles the buffer, if it is sufficiently large. That applies to both the left and the right argument. Although for string concatenation, applying the optimization if only the rhs is an rvalue can make things slower, if an allocation would be cheaper than copying the lhs.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson `String s2 = append("z", s1);` is faster than `String s2 = append(s1, "z");` since it copies the first argument in any case, and the contents of the second argument. For `append("z", s1)`, the temporary `"z"` can be moved to the parameter, and that move can be elided, so only the contents of the second argument are copied.

Comment: @dyp But this is not order-independent; string("foobar") != string("barfoo").

Comment: @dyp I think `S append(S, S const&); S append(S const&, S&&);` is unambiguous in all cases and near-optimal assuming a fast move constructor.

Comment: @Solkar The optimization requires a large enough buffer in any case. Also, the contents of one string have to be copied. If an allocation is more expensive than copying the contents of *both* strings, we can reuse the buffer of the rhs and profit. @ ecatmur Ah, great!

Comment: @dyp: I tried to address your concern by re-using the second argument's buffer in both the in-place and copy cases; hopefully not causing any ambiguity to arise.

Comment: @ecatmur Though it prefers the second overload if both are rvalues, which is not optimal for string concatenation :(

Comment: @dyp: That would need capacity(right_buffer) >= strlen(right) + max(strlen(left),strlen(right)); otherwise we'd need a pool or an alloc to store `right`  s content away from the cpy.

Comment: @Solkar Not sure I understand. You first move the contents of the rhs to the right to make space for the lhs, then you copy/move the contents of the lhs. Only requires `capacity(rhs) >= size(rhs) + size(lhs)`

Comment: @dyp Given, `capacity(rhs) >= strlen(rhs) + strlen(lhs)` + 1, if you move 'right' from tail to head. Question is, how expensive the necessary algorithmic  voodoo is is in total, when not just relatively small rights with monster buffers attached come along.

Comment: For many use cases, making append variadic (thus avoiding a lot of incremental resizes when concatenating several strings) will probably be much more important than exploiting the possibility that one argument's storage will be both available and sufficient. At that rate, I'd name the nonmember `concatenate` or something similar; `append` suggests, to me, modification.

Comment: Though that's not to say that storage reuse can't be important, too. It would be interesting to see how it impacts performance on average; it could easily make the operation significantly faster or... probably only slightly slower if no candidate is found.

Answer (score 0):

With the new move semantics you can write:

```
class A{
public:
    // this will get the property
    const dataType& PropertyName() const { return m_Property; }
    // this wil set the property
    dataType& PropertyName() { return m_Propery; }
private:
    dataType m_Propery;
};

main()
{
    A a;
    a.PropertyName() = someValueOfType_dataType; // set
    someOtherValueOfType_dataType = a.PropertyName(); // get
}
```

Comment: Where is this using move semantics?  This looks to me like valid C++03 code.

Comment: this is indeed valid C++03, or even older, code. But you'd get a performance hit for non-trivial data types because of the copying. With new C++11 compilers, the compiler will take care of moving instead of copying data (as long as the data type implements the right move assignment operator).

Comment: It's true (and mostly awesome) that C++11 injects moves into a lot of helpful places, but (under the assumption that `someValueOfType_dataType` and `someOtherValueOfType_dataType` are lvalues, which is what I would assume since they're written out like variables), I don't see any points in this code where that applies.  If the two values are intended to be rvalues, I would hint that by writing `move(foo)` around them.  (Or at least put empty parentheses after them so that they might be functions returning rvalues.)

Comment: This does not seem to address the OP's question, at all. And... no, there is no move here.